# cannot unserialize serialized getimagesize array from file

Tags: php

I have a file, "serialized.txt", which contains a serialized array (created by doing serialize($array)).

```
s:133:"a:7:{i:0;i:640;i:1;i:480;i:2;i:2;i:3;s:24:"width="640" height="480"";s:4:"bits";i:8;s:8:"channels";i:3;s:4:"mime";s:10:"image/jpeg";}";
```

To fetch the contents I do:

```
$string = file_get_contents("serialized.txt");
```

Then I do:

```
print_r(unserialize($string));
```

The output that I get:

```
a:7:{i:0;i:640;i:1;i:480;i:2;i:2;i:3;s:24:"width="640" height="480"";s:4:"bits";i:8;s:8:"channels";i:3;s:4:"mime";s:10:"image/jpeg";}
```

This is the unserialized version of the string (contents of the file) when it should be printing the unserialized array. If I copy the string and do the following:

```
print_r(unserialize('a:7:{i:0;i:640;i:1;i:480;i:2;i:2;i:3;s:24:"width="640" height="480"";s:4:"bits";i:8;s:8:"channels";i:3;s:4:"mime";s:10:"image/jpeg";}'));
```

I get the correct output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 640
    [1] => 480
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="640" height="480"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
```

So the problem seems to be isolated to the serialized array when pulling from the file.

According to the [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) docs the function should be returning **false** if there is a problem; not the contents of the string.

The serialized data is taken from [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and I have verified that if I serialize another array and place it into the file:

```
serialize(array("hi"));
```

I can successfully generate the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hi
)
```

Are there any ideas why this may be happening? A bug with the serialization process relating to a getimagesize array, or potentially a "hidden" character in the file that my copy and paste removes? I have millions of these files already generated so it's not possible for me to change the storage method. I guess the solution may just be to write my own parser to serialize the array? The input is always the same format so that's plausible, but I would like to know of this a bug or my error with something somewhere.

Comment: It's obvious that you serialized it twice when originally saving to the file.

Comment: You have serialized the string twice ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see your data is double serialized so the following code should print your array:

```
$string = file_get_contents("serialized.txt");
print_r(unserialize(unserialize($string)));
```

Although you should think about how you save to file. You may want to remove one serialization.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: ha! So it does. I thought something looked strange but I couldn't put my finger on it. I'll mark this as accepted once it allows me. Thanks.